# Unexpected implicit cast to LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

This is probably something really simple, but I'm an Android newbie. The code debugs fine, but when I try to generate a signed APK, I get build errors. Using Android Studio 3.0.1

**Error: Unexpected implicit cast to LayoutParams: layout tag was FrameLayout [WrongViewCast]**

This bit is where the error is highlighted 3 times in the code below (this is not the complete function, only the bit where the errors are highlighted):

**findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_2).getLayoutParams()).weight > 0)**

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    switch (mCurrentFragmentIndex) {
        case ALERTS_FRAGMENT_ID:
            if (getScreenWidth() >= dualFragmentWidth &&
                    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_2).getLayoutParams()).weight > 0) {
                shrinkSecondFragment();
                //unselect the list item
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout) != null) {
                    ((CollatedAlertsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout)).unselectItem();
                }
                return;
            }
            break;
        case MYSCHOOP_FRAGMENT_ID:
            if (getScreenWidth() >= dualFragmentWidth &&
                    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_2).getLayoutParams()).weight > 0) {
                shrinkSecondFragment();
                return;
            }
            break;
        case SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_ID:
            if (getScreenWidth() >= dualFragmentWidth &&
                    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_2).getLayoutParams()).weight > 0) {
                shrinkSecondFragment();
                return;
            }
            break;
```

This is the XML for **frame_layout_2**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Appreciate any help or advice. Thanks

Comment: `frame_layout_2` is a FrameLayout, not a LinearLayout.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice:  That doesn't matter.  The LayoutParams is given by the parent which is a LinearLayout.  The LayoutParams are going to be a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instance.

Comment: @DeeV I suggest that you verify that assumption

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i had read the exception wrong.

It's an implicit cast error, not an explicit cast error.

The issue is this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout)
```

Here android is trying to fetch a fragment with the id "frame_layout"

But this id belongs to a FrameLayout and not a fragment.

You should declare the tag with:

```
<fragment>
```

Comment: What you were doing was casting a view to a params object.

Comment: @DeeV yea it wouldn't even compile as they are unrelated classes completely

Comment: Can you clarify what I'm doing wrong? The underlined error is this part of the code:

findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_2).getLayoutParams()

Answer (score 0):

You need add another brackets around

`findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_2).getLayoutParams()`

for example,

`(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) (findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_2).getLayoutParams()).weight`

Comment: I tried not, but there's no difference.The error is not showing there's a bracket missing, it's saying:

Error:(678, 17) Error: Unexpected implicit cast to LayoutParams: layout tag was FrameLayout [WrongViewCast]